# toString and valueOf Execution order make me confused

Tags: javascript, tostring, value-of

the object f string conversion, but not call the prototype chain toString method

```js
function fn(){}

fn.prototype.toString = function(){
    console.log("toString call");
    return {};
}
fn.prototype.valueOf = function(){
    console.log("valueOf call");
    return 100;
}

let f = new fn();
console.log("before "+f+" after"); 

// I hope：toString call --> valueOf call --> 'before 100 after'
// Result: valueOf call --> 'before 100 after'
```

Comment: Try `console.log(200 + f)` to understand why only `valueOf` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
console.log(`before ${f} after`);
```

When using `+` (addition or string concatenation), the `hint` parameter that passed to [`[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) is `default`, which will call `valueOf()` by default.

But when using template string, the `hint` would be `string`, so `toString()` will be called first.

```js
function fn(){}

fn.prototype.toString = function(){
    console.log("toString call");
    return {};
}
fn.prototype.valueOf = function(){
    console.log("valueOf call");
    return 100;
}

let f = new fn();
console.log(`before ${f} after`);
```